# Image fit to screen.How to remove the scrollbar while adding header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Want to create a HTML page with image fit to screen,based on the screen size image displayed correctly without header and footer while adding header and footer it's appears vertical scroll bar.
[image]
 How to resolve this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
     <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}    
  .row  {
        display: table-row;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;

    }

.header, .footer{
    background: pink;
    display:table-row;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}    
 .content {
        display: table;
        background: brown;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
.left, .right{
    background: green;
    display: table-cell;
    width:10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.middle{
    background:white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}   </style>
<script>
    function winResized() { 
    var $image=$('#image');
    if ($image.size()) {
    var ww=$(window).width();
    var wh=$(window).height();
    var iw=$image.width();
    var ih=$image.height();
    var f=Math.min(ww/iw,wh/ih);
    var iwr=Math.round(iw*f);
    var ihr=Math.round(ih*f);
    $image.css({   
    'width': iwr,
    'height': ihr,
    'left': (Math.round(ww-iwr)/2)+'px',
    'top': (Math.round(wh-ihr)/2)+'px'
    });
    }
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
    winResized();
    }).bind('resize',function() {
    winResized();

    });
    </script>
    <body>
         <div id="container">
     <div class="header">
         <h4>header</h4>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left">Left </div>
            <div class="middle"><br/><center>
<img id="image" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/c050fce5e0094decb57fdb53f4ca4254.jpg"/>
</center>
            </div>
            <div class="right">Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h4>footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calc():

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/bNjayX

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 150px; background: red;"></div>
<div style="height: calc(100% - 250px); background: blue;"></div>
<div style="height: 100px; background: green;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are set the height of content class to 100%.

for solving this problem you can add this code for .content :

```
 .content {
    display: table;
    background: brown;
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

total height of your header and footer is 80px.(in your code)

Comment: you can set the header and footer position to fixed. or use(( height:100hv ))

Answer (score 0):

Though both the above answers might work.. calc doesnt have very good cross browsers support, you might need to check that out http://caniuse.com/

You can use absolute positioning and padding instead to achieve

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r1jcbzu4/

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.header {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
    height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  }

.main {
   height: 100%;
   padding: 100px 0px;
  background: #0f0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00f;
}
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='main'></div>
 <div class='footer'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already tried this, I am calculate the image size with  help of jquery  that time scroll is apprear. Plz verify the html Jquery part.